# Linear dependence proof

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, independence

I have to determine whether the vector system ($\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$) $|x|,|x+|x||,|x-|x||$ is linear independent. I tried the definition $\forall \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 \in K: \lambda_1a_1+\lambda_2a_2+\lambda_3a_3=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ and got that $\lambda_2=\lambda_3$, but got no information about $\lambda_1$ so I thought that maybe the system is linear dependent. Tried it and yes, if for example $\lambda_1=2$ then $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=-1$ and the equation $\lambda_1a_1+\lambda_2a_2+\lambda_3a_3=0$ still stands.

I am not sure how to prove that this is linear dependent, can someone help me with this one? (I have trouble with simplifying the absolute values)

Comment: what are the $x$ ? functions ? it's not totally clear.

Comment: it is said that the absolute values are vectors

Comment: You proved it already: $$2|x|-|x+|x||-|x-|x||=0$$ for all $x$.

Comment: It is that simple? :D Can I just take a $\lambda$ and show that if it's that, the equation works but all the lambda-s are not 0?